# OpenGL - Re-binding an already bound texture

Tags: c++, image, opengl, graphics, textures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making redundant OpenGL calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905728/making-redundant-opengl-calls)

Let's say I have an `Image` class that has a method called `draw` that draws a part of the image on the screen, and also stores a handle to a 2d texture that contains the actual image data.

Is it OK to implement the draw() method like this?

```
// ix, iy, w and h specify which part of the image to draw
void Image::draw(int x, int y, int ix, int iy, int w, int h)
{
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureHandle);
   //and then draw the specified part of the image
}
```

My main concern here is the call to `glBindTexture`. Is it correct to assume that if the texture is already bound, this call won't result in some kind of a performance hit?

Comment: It shouldn't cause much of a performance hit anyway.  If you really are worried about the performance of `glBindTexture`, have you tried timing the difference with and without `glBindTexture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked on some implementatioins (drivers) for OpenGL, OpenVG and similar, the glBindTexture really just stores the m_textureHandle in some "good place" inside the "current context". It is not a difficult thing to do, and shouldn't "cost much".

If you are trying to save every last cycle of execution, by all means add a variable to determine if you have already bound your texture, and only do it if needed. But in general, I would be very surprised if you can't save 5-10x the amount of time by doing other clever stuff.